# How to escape single quote characters in bash command substitution

Tags: bash, unix, sqoop

I want to generate a SQOOP command which is appended by some variable like `CUSTOM_PARAMS`.
I have defined the variable in a file : say `hi.cfg`

The variable have some single quotes as well like 'orc'.

> ```
> cat hi.cfg
> CUSTOM_PARAMS="--query select * from blah..blah where \$CONDITIONS --split-by blah --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-external-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza stored as 'orc' --compress --compression-codec 'snappy' --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 5 --target-dir /any/dir"
> ```

When  I source to the file on command prompt and do echo it gives me exactly whats written over there which looks correct.

> ```
> source hi.cfg
> echo "$CUSTOM_PARAMS"
> --query select * from blah..blah where $CONDITIONS --split-by blah --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-external-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza stored as 'orc' --compress --compression-codec 'snappy' --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 5 --target-dir /any/dir
> ```

But when I call this from a shell script as below :

> ```
> cat hi.sh
>
> echo "Generating Sqoop Command"
> source $HOME/hi.cfg
> echo "${CUSTOM_PARAMS}"
> SQOOP_COMMAND="SQOOP statement : sqoop import blah blah "$CUSTOM_PARAMS""
> echo $SQOOP_COMMAND
> ```

The * character in the variable is been treated as a command:

> ```
> sh hi.sh
>
> Generating Sqoop Command
> --query select * from blah..blah where $CONDITIONS --split-by blah --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-external-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza stored as 'orc' --compress --compression-codec 'snappy' --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 5 --target-dir /any/dir
> SQOOP statement : sqoop import blah blah --query select 0 00 000000_0 000073_0 000103_0 02 09.txt 1  from blah..blah where $CONDITIONS --split-by blah --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-external-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza stored as 'orc' --compress --compression-codec 'snappy' --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 5 --target-dir /any/dir
> ```

I need to run the SQOOP Statement later on in the script and have tried couple of options but didn't help.
I also tried  `\*` but didn't help, it outputs:

> ```
> Generating Sqoop Command
> --query select \* from blah..blah where $CONDITIONS --split-by blah --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-external-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza stored as 'orc' --compress --compression-codec 'snappy' --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 5 --target-dir /any/dir
> SQOOP statement : sqoop import blah blah --query select \* from blah..blah where $CONDITIONS --split-by blah --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-external-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza stored as 'orc' --compress --compression-codec 'snappy' --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 5 --target-dir /any/dir`
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

> ```
> SQOOP_COMMAND="SQOOP statement : sqoop import blah blah "$CUSTOM_PARAMS""
> ```

To this:

```
SQOOP_COMMAND="SQOOP statement : sqoop import blah blah $CUSTOM_PARAMS"
```

Also change this line:

> ```
> echo $SQOOP_COMMAND
> ```

To this:

```
echo "$SQOOP_COMMAND"
```

Or if you want to embed the extra double-quotes, then to this:

```
SQOOP_COMMAND="SQOOP statement : sqoop import blah blah \"$CUSTOM_PARAMS\""
```

What's happening is that the way you wrote it,
the first embedded double-quote closes the quoted expression.
Effectively you have there `SQOOP statement : sqoop import blah blah` quoted, followed by `$CUSTOM_PARAMS` unquoted,
followed by an empty string (`""`).
If you want to embed double-quotes within double-quotes,
then you need to escape them with `\`.

But it seems to me you don't want to embed double-quotes at all.